# How to deduct Newton's method heuristically

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, fixed-points

Let $\alpha$ be a fixed point of a contractive function $g$ defined in $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $g'(\alpha) = 0$ and $g''(\alpha) \neq 0$.

My first question is how to prove that $x_{k + 1} = g\left(x_k\right)$ converges to $\alpha$. I think that we can only use that $g$ is contractive, but how could we show it rigorously?

Then we know, by the Taylor's expansion of order $2$ of $g$ centered in $\alpha$, that the fixed point method has order $2$. I want to deduct heuristically the Newton's method to find a zero of $f$ applying the previous property to a fixed point function $g(x) = h(x)f(x)$ for some $h$. I'm so confused and I don't know how to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $g(x)=x+g_1(x)$. If one or more of the roots of $f$ are to be fixed points of $g$, then it has to be also a root of $g_1$, which is easiest to arrange via $g_1\sim f$ or $g_1(x)=h(x)f(x)$. Then the derivative of g is
$$
g'(x)=1+h'(x)f(x)+h(x)f'(x).
$$
The middle term is zero at the roots of $f$, and $1+h(α)f'(α)=0$ is easiest to guarantee if $h(x)=-f'(x)^{-1}$ everywhere.

Of course it is more intuitive to develop the Newton step as tangent root or as value at zero of a linear approximation of the inverse function.

Comment: But firstly $g(x) = h(x)f(x)$ right? I don't understand why we can write $g(x) = x + g_1(x)$... :(

Comment: With $g_1(x)=g(x)-x$ obviously. And then it is $g(x)=x+h(x)f(x)$.

Comment: The point is that $g=hf$ doesn't actually make sense if the goal is to have roots of $f$ be fixed points of $g$, because if $g=hf$ then roots of $f$ are roots of $g$. The right way to use an $hf$ type expression is as $g(x)=x+h(x) f(x)$.

Comment: So is there a typo in the statement and should the fixed point function be $g(x) = x + h(x)f(x)$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, but the statement says "the fixed point function $g(x) = h(x)f(x)$". I mean, should it be $g(x) = x + h(x)f(x)$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I was rephrasing your setup to the OP, emphasizing that the setup proposed in the OP to begin with doesn't make sense.

Comment: I did not scroll up far enough. Indeed, the formula in the hint is incomplete, you could check in your course materials if there are other places where it is this wrong. Or if there is a context where it is right.